# Records in table not showing on form Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

Excuse my ignorance in asking this question - I am a database novice and need help!

I will explain as best I can.

In the table on my DB I have 235 records.  I have created a form which references that table and which is pulling through only 226 of those records - for some reason it will not display the last 9.

What have I done wrong?

I input all the data using an import so I did them all the same way.

Thanks and please let me know if I have not made sense I can explain further!

Comment: It's hard to debug code we cannot see :) For example, adding the `DISTINCT` keyword to the `SELECT` clause could cause rows to 'disappear'. A complete stab in the dark, of course!

Answer (score 3):

If you import data and it seemingly disappears, you need to check the indexes on that table. You should do the following:

- Switch the table into **Design View**
- In the **Table Tools** Section, under the **Design** Tab, click on **Indexes**
- You will see a list of Indexes pop up

If any of the Indexes have one or more columns that are unique, those rows may have vanished upon import. You may need to either remove all indexes (do not touch the PrimaryKey) or Change the Unique Property on all Indexes from `Yes` to `No`.

Then, just reimport the data.

If all 235 rows are in the table already, go to your form's Property sheet. Click the Data Tab. Look at the Record Source and see if it is a table name or query.

You need to also go back to the Property Sheet, Click the Format Tab. Look over the Default View and set it to **Single Form**. This will view the table rows one row at a time. Click the Last Record Navigation Button. It had better say `235 of 235`.